# Contact form 7 keep spinning after file upload

Tags: wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I'm using Contact form 7 for my wordpress site that allow users to fill in their info and attach Cv with file types are:  pdf/doc/docx.
When I test the form without attaching the CV, it works fine, but when I upload a CV, it keeps spinning and no response.
I don't know if this is a bug of this plugin or my configuration is wrong?
I'd be appreciated if there's any help.

```
<label style="font-size:18px">Personal Info</label>
<label class="form-submission-label"> <span>Mail</span>[text* text-115] </label>

<label class="form-submission-label"> <span>Name</span> <span class="form-name">[text* your-name] [text text-182] </span ></label>

<label  class="form-submission-label"> <span>Nickname(Optional)</span> <span class="form-name"> [text* your-name][text text-183]</span > </label>

<label  class="form-submission-label"> <span class="dob-label">Birthday</span><label class="dob">[number* number-722 min:1 max:31][number* number-723 min:1 max:12][number* number-724 min:1980 max:2000]</label></label>


<label  class="form-submission-label"> <span>Address</span>[text* text-116] </label>

<label  class="form-submission-label"> <span>Contact number</span> [tel* tel-565] </label>

<label  class="form-submission-label"><span>SkypeID （Optional）</span>[text text-117]
</label>

<label style="font-size:18px">Work Experience</label>

<label  class="form-submission-label"><span>Current company</span>[text* text-119]
</label>

<label  class="form-submission-label"><span>Position</span>[text* text-120]
</label>

<label  class="form-submission-label"><span>Years of experience</span>[text* text-121]
</label>

<label  class="form-submission-label"><span>Desired position</span>[text text-232]
</label>
<label  class="form-submission-label"><span>Desired salary</span>[text text-904]
</label>

<label class="form-submission-label"><span>CV attachment (Optional)</span>[file file-637 limit:10mb filetypes:pdf|docx|doc]
</label>

<label class="submit-label">[submit "Send my info"]</label>
```

Comment: what is the error in console?

Comment: it shows no error, but keeps spinning and no response

Comment: please share you site url

Comment: sorry I can't, the website is still in development and due to security of my organization, we're not allowed to share the URL :(

Comment: please enable the `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` true and check the error

Answer (score 0):

Harley Liang ... you can try this..

Method 1 – Change Permalink Structure to Default

Method 2 – Disable Ajax Load in functions.php

```
define( 'WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false);
```